# How to compile shader files in UWP

Tags: shaders, hlsl, windows, sharpdx

I wish to use this method

```
byte[] vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(".......Transf_VS.hlsl", "VS", "vs_5_0");
                this.vertexShader = new D3D11.VertexShader(
                    device,
                    vertexShaderByteCode
                    );
```

But it throws exception of either file not found or file cannot be open.

Is there any solution to this? I saw HelixToolkit using shader files that has already been compiled, how is it done then?
https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/master/Source/HelixToolkit.UWP/Model/ExampleCube3D.cs

```
// Loads vertex shader bytecode
            var vertexShaderByteCode = NativeFile.ReadAllBytes(path + "\\MiniCube_VS.fxo");
            this.vertexShader = new VertexShader(d3dDevice, vertexShaderByteCode);
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked that the filepath is valid?

Comment: I have modified it several times, and sometimes it says cannot open instead of cannot find, so I know that's when it's valid

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132838/i-dont-think-my-shaders-are-working-looking-for-help Here is a possible solution to the problem, but there is still no display so I'm not sure whether the problem is finally solved. Please check this latter question and share your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution without explanation, it should apply for UWP apps:

**I manually put the shader files in a directory** like this

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "ProjectName")
```

which in my case would be

```
F:\*****\SolutionFolder\StartupProjectFolder\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\FolderWithCurrentProjectName
```

Then the compiler can read the shader files, it works for either fx. files(hlsl source code) and fxo. files(compiled before the whole solution with another program the fxc.exe).
The second method can use the guidance fromhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293760/creating-fxo-shader-file-using-fxc-exe

**There are other complications that one might want to notice**

1. the visual studio create txt. files with UTF-8 coding, you may want to check out in ASCII coding to remove the chars at the beginning of a file, which may cause problem.
2. fxc.exe can be found for example in this directory

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
3. You'd better copy the fxc.exe into another folder to run it, the directory of the exe. file and source file would better not contain blanks in any of its folder names in the path.

The idea comes from the example made by HelixToolkit. You see there are lot of bumps in route and since few are doing sharpdx + uwp right now we have to sweep them ourselves. I hope this can help others who face the same problem, and of course I hope there are pros who can explain why this works and otherwise it doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression you had to have precompiled shader files under UWP.  There is a tool, and info in the MSDN site for compiling files.

Apologies if this is not completely correct, more here say on my front.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509633(v=vs.85).aspx#compiling_at_build_time_to_object_files

Comment: Your answer sounds a little bit confusing, and may have been better as a comment. Do you meant to say you heard this is true, but apart from that, have no real idea if it is?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132838/i-dont-think-my-shaders-are-working-looking-for-help Here is a possible solution to the problem, but there is still no display so I'm not sure whether the problem is finally solved. Please check this latter question and share your view

Answer (score 0):

If you look at my answer to another question I show the steps of setting Visual Studio to compile shaders with a separate C++ project, you could use it the same way but just have the output option in the HLSL compiler tab set to your folder, that way you can build your shaders in VS and if you read my full answer I have a link to a nice tool as well.

First up make a new C++ project and call it shader builder, add a filter called shaders and then follow [these steps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131240/debugging-fx-files-in-visual-studio-not-working/131263#131263)