# I don't think my shaders are working, looking for help

Tags: shaders, directx11, hlsl, windows, sharpdx

Using sharpdx(directx 11) developing on UWP.

This is a link to a previous question of not being able to compile the shader files(written in hlsl) [How to compile shader files in UWP](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/how-to-compile-shader-files-in-uwp/132830#132830) Later I have found some method to avoid the original exception(unable to open or find shader files) but still the shaders seem not to be working.

**My method** to "avoid the original exception" is to change the file path to

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "ProjectName")
```

If the method works, I would surely post it as an answer to the previous question

**The current problem** is no display on the screen(all black), while I can check the stored data in the vertex buffer using graphic diagnostics tools built in visual studio.
[image: Vertex buffer works fine, it seems]

Here is my code for the shaders, problem may be going from here because this is the first shader file I've written. Please have a look and discuss may things go wrong.

pixel shader file Pixel_PS.fx

```
struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

float4 PS(VertexOut pin) : SV_Target
{
    return pin.Color;
}
```

vertes shader file Transf_VS.fx

```
cbuffer dataBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix ViewProjection;  
};

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout;
    // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
    vout.PosH = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), ViewProjection);
    // Just pass vertex color into the pixel shader.
    vout.Color = vin.Color;
    return vout;
}
```

where I compiled them

```
byte[] vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(this.path + "\\Transf_VS.fx", "VS", "vs_5_0");
                this.vertexShader = new D3D11.VertexShader(
                    device,
                    vertexShaderByteCode
                    );
                this.inputSignature = new ShaderSignature(vertexShaderByteCode);
                this.pixelShader = new D3D11.PixelShader(
                    device,
                    ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile(this.path + "\\Pixel_PS.fx", "PS", "ps_5_0")
                    );
```

data structure definition

```
public struct ScatterVertex
    {
        SharpDX.Vector3 Position;
        SharpDX.Color4 Color;
    }
```

inputlayout initialization

```
this.inputLayout = new D3D11.InputLayout(
                    this.device,
                    inputSignature,
                    new SharpDX.Direct3D11.InputElement[]
                    {
                        new D3D11.InputElement(
                            "Position",
                            0,
                            SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R32G32B32_Float,
                            0
                            ),
                        new D3D11.InputElement(
                            "Color",
                            0,
                            SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R32G32B32A32_Float,//I'm not very sure whether or why I should use this option
                            0
                            )
                    }
                    );
```

Here's the projection matrix in the camera class, which is later sent to the constant buffer

```
private Matrix View { get { return Matrix.LookAtLH(this.Eye, this.Target, this.Up); } }
private Matrix Proj { get { return Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(this.Fov, this.Aspect, this.Near, this.Far); } }
public Matrix WorldViewProject
        {
            get
            {
                Matrix wvp = (this.View * this.Proj);
                wvp.Transpose();
                return wvp;
            }
        }
```

If you need anything else to solve this, just let me know and I'll manage to get it.
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately in graphics programming 'blank screen' can come about for any number of reasons. Where is the code where you update the ``ViewProjection`` value in your constant buffer?

Comment: It's a bit long, let me check it myself first

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it!

It turns out the problem is not with the shader, but the `Draw` method. I missed setting the first parameter of draw in my code, which should be the primitives I am intending to draw.

Thanks to everyone in this discussion and that of the previous question, I will update the answer to the previous question in very short time.

Comment: Mark it as answered