# HLSL sampler always returns white

Tags: hlsl, fragment-shader

I'm having an issue with a simple HLSL pixel shader. As a start to writing a lighting engine, I created a point light texture that looks like this. The texture itself is a white -> transparent gradient, drawn here on a black background for visibility.

[image]

As a simple test, I wrote a shader to sample from that light texture. Here's the HLSL code.

```
texture2D pointLightTexture;

sampler pointLightSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <pointLightTexture>;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION0;
    float2 TexCoords : TEXCOORD0;
};

float4 PointLightFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    return tex2D(pointLightSampler, input.TexCoords);
}

technique PointLightTechnique
{
    pass Pass0
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0 PointLightFunction();
    }
};
```

But the resulting "light" is just a pure white rectangle.

[image]

So my basic question is, why is this texture sampling not working? I've already verified that 1) the texture is correct (I can draw the texture in isolation and it looks fine) and 2) the texture coordinates within the shader are correct (i.e. they properly span 0 to 1 within the bounds of that white square). In the past, I've run into issues when trying to use multiple samplers within one shader, but as you can see, this shader just has one.

More generally, I've been getting extremely frustrating using HLSL shaders. It seems very difficult to do even basic tasks, even when I know my logic is correct (i.e. draw a square and sample from the texture appropriately). Feels like the shader compiler optimizes the code so aggressively that most shaders just don't work. Further more, it seems silly that I should have to 1) store the point light texture and 2) create a sampler specifically using that texture, rather than just being able to call `pointLightTexture.Sample(pointLightSampler, input.TexCoords);`.

Is there something fundamentally I'm missing? Is there a way to disable HLSL's crazy optimizations? Is it an issue using Monogame? It seems crazy to me that I constantly have to fight against these shaders.

Comment: is your blend state set to alpha? Also there isn't really a problem with HLSL its just a pain sometimes, there a few tools that you can use to make it easier. That part about the sampler for bound to a texture is a DirectX 9 thing that is proly left in mono for compatibility with XNA.  Mono sucks, over abstracted and hides way to much from you..... SharpDX is the way to go as you can just read the MSDN docs and see how it works.

Comment: It wasn't, but no change after setting it to alpha blend. Thanks for the information on the rest though.

Comment: what format is your texture? try drawing it with spritebatch and see if it works

Comment: The texture is a "normal" texture? I'm sure that's not the answer you're looking for. Still, drawing it with SpriteBatch works correctly.

Comment: Well .png stores the alpha funny and .dds stores it correct. Also something that may help with your shaders https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimGJones.HLSLToolsforVisualStudio I was asking about spritebatch to see if its a problem with the shader or the texture...... just working over a list of things it could be

Comment: HLSL Tools looks great! Thank you! And I agree with working through potential problems. These HLSL issues are frustrating because I don't know how to attempt to fix them without asking for help.

Comment: I have an answer around here that walks you through the steps of setting up Visual Studio to work better with shaders, lets you compile them just like any other code file in your project and gives you error output too

Comment: That would certainly be helpful. The Monogame content project can already give me some information (like syntax errors). It's these graphical issues and optimization problems that are tricky.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/131240/debugging-fx-files-in-visual-studio-not-working/131263#131263  Also try firing up the VS Graphics debugger and inspect all the data in your pipeline.

Comment: It seems some serious DirectX research is in my future.

Comment: Make sure your ``VertexShaderOutput`` matches the output of whatever you are using for a  vertex shader. Your current order is a little unorthodox..

Comment: I'm a little confused. I have VertexShaderOutput declared the way it is because it's the only way I found to have shaders work with Monogame at all. Part of the confusion is that I'm not trying to write a vertex shader at all. I assumed I could just write the pixel shader given proper coordinates (which I have) and it would work.